# Find error in proof for $f(x) < g(x) \implies \lim_{x\to a}f(x) < \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

I know that it is not true that $f(x) < g(x) \implies \lim_{x\to a}f(x) < \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$

A counter example could be
$f(x) = 0$
$g(x) = |x|$ if $x\neq 0,\quad g(0) = 1$
$a=0$

However, before I thought about it I came up with the following proof and now I can't see what is wrong with it:

Let $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L_1, \quad \lim_{x\to a}g(x) = L_2$
We use proof by contradiction, so assume $L_1 \geq L_2$

As a first case, assume $L_1 = L_2 = L$.
Since $f(x) < g(x)$ we can set $d_g = g(x) - f(x) > 0$
We know there is a $\delta$ such that, if we set $\epsilon = \dfrac{d_g}{2}$

$|x-a| <  \delta \implies \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  |f(x) - L| < \dfrac{d_g}{2} \implies L - \dfrac{d_g}{2} < f(x) < L + \dfrac{d_g}{2} \\
  |f(x) + d_g - L| < \dfrac{d_g}{2} \implies L - \dfrac{3d_g}{2} < f(x) < L - \dfrac{d_g}{2}
 \end{array}
\right.$

So $f(x) < L - \frac{d_g}{2} < f(x)$. A contradiction, so $L_1 \neq L_2$

As a second case, assume $L_1 > L_2$.
Set $d_L = L_1 - L_2 > 0$
We know there is a $\delta$ such that, if we set $\epsilon = \dfrac{d_L}{2}$

$|x-a| <  \delta \implies \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  |f(x) - (L_2 + d_L) | < \dfrac{d_L}{2} \implies L + \dfrac{d_L}{2} < f(x) < L + \dfrac{3d_L}{2} \\
  |g(x) - L_2| < \dfrac{d_L}{2} \implies L - \dfrac{d_L}{2} < g(x) < L+ \dfrac{d_L}{2}
 \end{array}
\right.$

So $g(x) < L + \dfrac{d_L}{2} < f(x)$. A contradiction, so $L_1 \leq L_2$

The two cases together shows that $L_1 < L_2$.

Comment: $d_g$ can't be independent of $x$ in the example, because in fact they get close together near $x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot correlate a constant $d_g$ to be independent of the functions you equate them with. They have a straight relationship and they collapse together when $x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Oh, I see. So it is because in the definition of a limit, strictly speaking, $x$ is introduced after $\delta$ and thus can't be used to define $\delta$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. When you are using a definition and generally in mathematics, you are strictly defining units. So, d as a constant being independent is a mistake and of course cannot be used.

Comment: By the way, remember please to approve the questions. An answered question should be go as answered and approved thread if it fits you (you forgot to do that in the previous limit question I fully answered you as well).

Comment: I know that, but you can not approve at once and in the previous question I did not understand your explanation so I just upvoted and left the question for a while to see if I can understand your explanation later.

Comment: I edited it. The proof in your book had typo error between a and 0. Go check it please :)

Comment: I reformed my answer after I found the typo.

Comment: Yeah I  checked it before and I am really sorry but I can still not understand it haha :(

Comment: Haha no problem, you can go ask me there what you don't understand and explain it to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39306/discussion-between-charalampos-filippatos-and-hampadampadoo).